# Undefined method [] for nil when trying to run cap deploy:restart

Tags: capistrano

I have a Rails 5.2 app, and with cap 3.4.1 we are suddenly getting this weird error:

```
    [b35efe76]  Phusion Passenger(R) 6.0.8
     DEBUG [b35efe76] Finished in 0.305 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
    (Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
    cap aborted!
    SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@host.com: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Trying to narrow it down, it happens when attempting to restart, because this is the line that fails:

```
cap production deploy:restart
```

The question is, how do I go about finding what file is trying to call [] on a nil value on?  Running cap with --trace is of no value because it just gives me internal errors - nothing in my code.  Basically, how do I find out what is nil?

One more clue, currently, I have a bunch of servers, if I run the cap restart command on server A, it restarts fine, on server B, it throws this error, so I'm guessing there's an environment variable on server A but not B, but the error is just so opaque I don't know where to begin.

Thanks for any help,
kevin

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A wild guess: I had a similar problem and I could solve it by upgrading `capistrano-passenger` to `>= 0.2.1`

[Looks like](https://makandracards.com/makandra/497406-capistrano-deployment-issue-undefined-method-for-nil-nilclass) the version change of passenger from 6.0.7 to 6.0.8 has introduces a problem. I see you are also on 6.0.8, so it might affect you, too!

[Link to the capistrano-passenger issue](https://github.com/capistrano/passenger/issues/52)

Comment: Worked for me also!!!